# How to Client SSL-Authenticate enable the WSO2 IS (5.2) admin app?

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am working with WSO2 IS V5.2 and I have been able to configure the WSO2 IS with my own-issued server cert and also enabled it to accept client certs issued by my test CA, at least for transport (when I use a browser to access the admin app, I get a popup and select a client cert and then I get to the login page for the admin app).

I want to use client cert authentication to access the WSO2 IS administration app (https://:9443/carbon), but I have not been able to accomplish that yet, and have tried many different things but so far.

Does anyone know what needs to be done to get the admin app to accept the SSL authentication?

Thanks,
Jim

EDIT 1:  I've tried to implement the suggested changes, but so far, when I hit the https://:8443/carbon, I get a cert popup and then I get to the console login page with no login having taken place.

I've tried to configure the log4j.properties, but when I do the test above (hitting the /carbon with a browser with a client cert), there is absolutely nothing additional output to the log files.

Here's the log4j.properties I have now.  Can someone suggest how I can change it to give me more output about what might be happening?

Thanks!

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CARBON_CONSOLE, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY, CARBON_SYS_LOG

log4j.logger.AUDIT_LOG=INFO, AUDIT_LOGFILE
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.writer.PrettyPrinter=ERROR, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.clustering=INFO, CARBON_CONSOLE, CARBON_LOGFILE
log4j.logger.org.apache=DEBUG, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.tomcat=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.apacheds=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.server.ldap=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.server.core.event=WARN
log4j.logger.com.atomikos=INFO,ATOMIKOS
log4j.logger.org.quartz=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.juddi=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.digester.Digester=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.qpid=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.qpid.server.Main=INFO
log4j.logger.qpid.message=WARN
log4j.logger.qpid.message.broker.listening=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.tiles=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.coyote=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.solr=ERROR
log4j.logger.me.prettyprint.cassandra.hector.TimingLogger=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.wso2=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.enterprise=DEBUG, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.shared.ldap=DEBUG, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers=DEBUG, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY
#Following are to remove false error messages from startup (IS)
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.entry.DefaultServerAttribute=DEBUG, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService=DEBUG, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.ldif.LdifReader=ERROR, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapProtocolHandler=DEBUG, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.server.core=DEBUG, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY
log4j.logger.org.apache.directory.server.ldap.LdapSession=DEBUG, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY
#Hive Related Log configurations
log4j.logger.DataNucleus=ERROR
log4j.logger.Datastore=ERROR
log4j.logger.Datastore.Schema=ERROR
log4j.logger.JPOX.Datastore=ERROR
log4j.logger.JPOX.Plugin=ERROR
log4j.logger.JPOX.MetaData=ERROR
log4j.logger.JPOX.Query=ERROR
log4j.logger.JPOX.General=ERROR
log4j.logger.JPOX.Enhancer=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive=WARN
log4j.logger.hive=WARN
log4j.logger.ExecMapper=WARN
log4j.logger.ExecReducer=WARN
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.user.core=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.application=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework=DEBUG
 #log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt=DEBUG
 #log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2=DEBUG
 #log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim=DEBUG
 #log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt=DEBUG
 #log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning=DEBUG
 #log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.account.association=DEBUG
 #log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.mgt=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.security=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.core=DEBUG

log4j.logger.trace.messages=TRACE,CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE

log4j.additivity.org.apache.axis2.clustering=false
log4j.additivity.com.atomikos=false
log4j.additivity.org.apache=false

# CARBON_CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CARBON_CONSOLE=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.appenders.CarbonConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CARBON_CONSOLE.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
# ConversionPattern will be overridden by the configuration setting in the DB
log4j.appender.CARBON_CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %P%5p {%c} - %x %m%n
log4j.appender.CARBON_CONSOLE.layout.TenantPattern=%U%@%D[%T]
log4j.appender.CARBON_CONSOLE.threshold=DEBUG

# CARBON_MEMORY is set to be a MemoryAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY=org.wso2.carbon.logging.service.appender.CarbonMemoryAppender
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.bufferSize=200
# ConversionPattern will be overridden by the configuration setting in the DB
#log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %5p - %x %m {%c}%n
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.layout.ConversionPattern=TID: [%T] [%S] [%d] %P%5p {%c} - %x %m {%c}%n
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.layout.TenantPattern=%U%@%D [%T] [%S]
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.columnList=%T,%S,%A,%d,%c,%p,%m,%H,%I,%Stacktrace
log4j.appender.CARBON_MEMORY.threshold=DEBUG


# CARBON_LOGFILE is set to be a DailyRollingFileAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.appenders.CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender
# Log file will be overridden by the configuration setting in the DB
# This path should be relative to WSO2 Carbon Home
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/${instance.log}/wso2carbon${instance.log}.log
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
# ConversionPattern will be overridden by the configuration setting in the DB
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=TID: [%T] [%S] [%d] %P%5p {%c} - %x %m %n
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.layout.TenantPattern=%U%@%D [%T] [%S]
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.threshold=DEBUG

log4j.appender.CARBON_SYS_LOG = org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.CARBON_SYS_LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CARBON_SYS_LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %5p {%c} - %x %m %n
log4j.appender.CARBON_SYS_LOG.SyslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.CARBON_SYS_LOG.Facility=USER
log4j.appender.CARBON_SYS_LOG.threshold=DEBUG

# LOGEVENT is set to be a LogEventAppender using a PatternLayout to send logs to LOGEVENT
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT=org.wso2.carbon.logging.service.appender.LogEventAppender
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.url=tcp://10.100.3.103:7611
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.columnList=%T,%S,%A,%d,%c,%p,%m,%H,%I,%Stacktrace
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.userName=admin
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.password=admin
#log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.password=secretAlias:Log4j.Appender.LOGEVENT.Password

# Appender config to CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE
log4j.appender.CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/${instance.log}/wso2carbon-trace-messages${instance.log}.log
log4j.appender.CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
log4j.appender.CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %P%5p {%c} - %x %m %n
log4j.appender.CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE.layout.TenantPattern=%U%@%D [%T] [%S]
log4j.appender.CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE.threshold=TRACE
log4j.additivity.trace.messages=false

# Appender config to AUDIT_LOGFILE
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.appenders.CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/audit.log
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %P%5p {%c}- %x %m %n
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.layout.TenantPattern=%U%@%D [%T] [%S]
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.threshold=INFO
log4j.additivity.AUDIT_LOG=false

# Appender config to send Atomikos transaction logs to new log file tm.out.
log4j.appender.ATOMIKOS = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ATOMIKOS.File = repository/logs/tm.out
log4j.appender.ATOMIKOS.Append = true
log4j.appender.ATOMIKOS.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ATOMIKOS.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

# This file is used to override the default logger settings, and is used to remove unwanted logs from Shindig appearing on the console.

# Specification of Handler used by Console Logger
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

# Replacing default INFO level with SEVERE
#java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=SEVERE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=DEBUG

# - ADDED
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.custom.user.operation.event.listener=DEBUG
```

I am following this page to create the SSO provider:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+SSO+for+WSO2+Servers#EnablingSSOforWSO2Servers-ConfiguringWSO2IdentityServer

I add the SAML2 Web SSO Configuration.  In that I set the Assertion Consumer URLs to

https://nodejs3.whatever.com:8443/carbon/   (nodejs3.whatever.com is the hostname for the wso2 machine)

Default Assertion Consumer URL is same as the above.

Certificate Alias is wso2carbon.cert  (??)

Are the URLs above the correct ones?

Is the Certificate Alias correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to achieve this using the [X509 authenticator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/X509Certificate+Authenticator) and [carbon SAML authenticator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Logging+in+to+WSO2+Products+via+Identity+Server).

You can configure IS Admin console to use SAML SSO login with same IS. For that you'll have to login first as usual with admin credentials, create a service provider for Admin console, enable SAML authenticator and restart (Refer [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Logging+in+to+WSO2+Products+via+Identity+Server)).

Then follow [X509 authenticator configuration](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+X509Certificate+Authenticator) page to enable certificate authentication and update the service provider you created to use X509 authenticator.

Comment: For creating the SAML authenticator, do in step 11 of https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+SSO+for+WSO2+Servers#EnablingSSOforWSO2Servers-ConfiguringWSO2IdentityServer, do I have to create 3 different service providers (for a, b, and c)?

Comment: No, you can create a single service provider to represent the IS. And when creating the service provider give the relavent urls related to IS.

Comment: @farasath - thanks!  I think I got something messed up now, when I attempt to go the /carbon, I get the cert popup, and select the cert I made for user "admin", then, I still get the login page, but then if I try to log in as admin/admin, the page just hangs!  I don't see any add'l output in any of the logs - is there somewhere to turn up the logging to see what might be happening?

Comment: you can enable debug logs in is_home/repository/conf/log4j.properties